# Symfony Panther TransportException

Tags: laravel, symfony

Me he instalado el componente [Panther](https://github.com/symfony/panther) de Symfony a una aplicación en laravel 10, hasta aqui todo normal.

Intentando realizar el uso básico:

```
$client = Client::createChromeClient();
// Or, if you care about the open web and prefer to use Firefox
$client = Client::createFirefoxClient();

$client->request('GET', 'https://api-platform.com'); // Yes, this website is 100% 
written in JavaScript
$client->clickLink('Get started');
```

Siempre obtengo el siguiente error

> Symfony
>  \ 
> Component
>  \ 
> HttpClient
>  \ 
> Exception
>  \ 
> TransportException
> Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9515: Connection refused for "http://127.0.0.1:9515/status".

¿Como puedo configurar de manera correcta Panther para realizar Scrapping?